# Add wait for POST request to Slack API

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, slack, slack-api

I want to send message to Slack hook using JavaScript code:

```
const slackEndpoint = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/.........';
   axios.post(slackEndpoint,
      {text: message})
      .then(response =>{
        return response.statusText})
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

But from time to time I get timeout. I tried to add `await` like this:

```
const slackEndpoint = 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/.........';
   await axios.post(slackEndpoint,
      {text: message})
      .then(response =>{
        return response.statusText})
      .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

But when I send a message nothing happens.
Do you know what might be the issue?

Comment: I don't think adding an await does anything here. please may you clarify what you mean by _"nothing happens"_?

Comment: when using `.then`, you don't need await.

Comment: Can you propose some solution, please?

Comment: `But from time to time I get timeout.` can you expand more on this please?